# GCP App Engine Build fails over torch installation

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, pytorch

I am deploying FastAPI app using PyTorch as requirements. The build fails most of the time and succeed when I remove PyTorch from requirements.txt.
Here is my configuration:

***app.yaml***

```
env: standard
runtime: python310
instance_class: F2
entrypoint: gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app
automatic_scaling:
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.65
  min_instances: 5
  max_instances: 100
  min_pending_latency: 30ms
  max_pending_latency: automatic
  max_concurrent_requests: 50
```

***cloudbuild.yaml***

```
# [START cloudbuild]
steps:
# Install dependencies
- name: 'python'
  entrypoint: pip3
  args: ['install', '-r', 'requirements.txt']
# Run custom commands
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 1600 && gcloud app deploy']
timeout: '6000s'

# [END cloudbuild]
```

***requirements.txt***

```
torch
fastapi
uvicorn[standard]
gunicorn
sqlalchemy
google-api-python-client 
google-auth-httplib2 
google-auth-oauthlib
pydantic
transformers
cloud-sql-python-connector
pg8000
```

What should be changed to the configuration to make the deployment successful?

Comment: Have you maxed out memory?

Comment: Can you try to use a flex environment?

Comment: I am using flex now and it works but I had to downgrade my app to python 3.7 as this is the latest version supported by flex env.

Comment: What is the app you're deploying? Are you serving models? Helping your users train models? I would simplify your deployment requirements to get things working first, for example, put _only_ `runtime: python310` in `app.yaml` (going back to Std instead of Flex), don't have a `cloudbuild.yaml` file, and delete everything from `requirements.txt` except `torch` and get it working. Once you're there, then slowly add req'd pieces for your app. IOW, go agile. Another alternative is to try to deploy to Cloud Run instead of App Engine (compare both via my Reddit comment at http://reddit.com/qsx4xh )